# Can I extend all objects (not just winforms control) in .Net to have a tag property?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Assuming I was writing my own version of .Net :)

What would be the downside of such a setup?

Yes, I am talking about a new anti-pattern here to avoid creating endless tuples and EventArgs. I think such a setup would have made coding a lot cleaner.

Comment: When you have a heavyweight object, like a control, the overhead of a tag is fairly insignificant. But having an additional tag member on ALL objects - that could have a significant impact on the memory footprint of small objects.

Comment: Tag is a generic term, how would it be useful if every object had it?  It sounds like you're trying to invent a new anti-pattern.

Comment: Use custom classes, derive from the other ones that are close to what you need, but could use some other useful adornments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The Tag property has history, it was important in VB6 and Winforms was meant to replace it.  It needed to be added to make porting code relatively simple.

It is entirely unnecessary in .NET.  It supports implementation inheritance, a feature that VB6 didn't have.  So if you want to add extra properties then you just derive a class and add them.  And you'll be able to give them a good name and a type so you don't have to cast every time you read the property.  This works just as well with Winforms controls.